# Image Upload to Express Server via CKEditor 5 gives Multer Error in Angular Application

Tags: angular, express, ckeditor, multer, ckeditor5

I am using CKEditor (@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic) for my Angular App. I have an issue when uploading the image from the front end to back end. The back end route runs fine. I tested it on Postman to post an image successfully. But when I use CKFinder to upload image from Ckeditor to Express backend, it gives "MulterError: Unexpected field".
This is my Express Route for image upload.

```
router.post('/archive', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.file) {
        return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Upload fail'});
    } else {
       html = "";
       html += "<script type='text/javascript'>";
       html += "    var funcNum = " + req.query.CKEditorFuncNum + ";";
       html += "    var url     = \"/public/images/" + req.file.filename + "\";";
       html += "    var message = \"Uploaded file successfully\";";
       html += "";
       html += "    window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url, message);";
       html += "</script>";

      res.send(html);
        //req.body.imageUrl = 'http://public/images/' + req.file.filename;
        Gallery.create(req.body, function (err, gallery) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return next(err);
            }
            res.json(gallery);
        });
    }
});
```

And this is the angular code I'm using in my component for saving image to the backend.

```
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';

public editor = ClassicEditor;

    public config:any = {
    ckfinder: {
      options: {
          resourceType: 'Images'
      },
      uploadUrl: 'http://localhost:3000/gallery/archive/'
    }
  }
```

I think the problem is with my uploadUrl but I don't know what it is. Can someone please give pointers in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank You.

**EDIT**

My Multer Configuration:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, './public/images');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      //console.log(file);
      var filetype = '';
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/gif') {
        filetype = 'gif';
      }
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
        filetype = 'png';
      }
      if(file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
        filetype = 'jpg';
      }
      cb(null, 'image-' + Date.now() + '.' + filetype);
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage: storage});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the error that tells that the `fieldName` is not matched. You have specified in the beckend that the `fieldname` is `'file'`, so when you are sending image to the backend, you need to specify the same name `'file'` in the frontend.

Or you can change your backend code from `upload.single('file')` to `upload.any()`.

Comment: I did as you suggested and switched to upload.any(). Now the image gets saved in the public/images folder when I upload it with CKEditor, but it gives me a 500 internal server error. And the image does not show in the component. The Sever returns a fieldname of 'upload' for the images  when I console.log it.

Comment: Try `console.log('Uploaded Image: ', req.file)` and check if you are sending the correct `url` as response.

Comment: The console.log returns nothing. I only get this error in the browser: POST http://localhost:3000/gallery/archive/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Can you copy your `Multer` configuration here? And do the `console.log()` after the `router.post('/archive', upload.single('file'), function(req, res, next) {` to check if it is executed.

Comment: I console.logged right after `router.post('/archive', upload.any(), function(req, res, next) {` and it returns undefined

Comment: Ok, try `console.log('Uploaded Images: ', req.files)`... If you are uploading multiple images then they will be populated in `req.files` and not in `req.file` property.

Comment: I am only trying to upload one image so far. I haven't tried to upload multiple images.

Comment: Yeah, but maybe that CKEditor are sending an array of images that have only one image. Try `console.log(req.files)`.

Comment: Yes CKEditor is sending an array of images when I console.logged it.

Comment: That is why you have an error. You are using `req.file.filename` and `req.file` does not exist. You should change `req.file.filename` to `req.files[0].filename` if you are uploading only one image. Also in `if` statement, change `req.file` to `req.files`

Comment: Now it's giving a new error: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client  :(

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client

Comment: It is because when you do `res.send(html)`, the response will be send. And you are trying to send it again after with `res.json(gallery);`

Comment: So, I removed the res.json(gallery) option. Now there are no more errors. No errors in the console or browser. The image I upload gets saved to the public/images folder, but the browser still refuses to upload the image. It says: "localhost: 4200 Cannot upload file." Is this a problem with the uploadUrl I am providing in ckifnder??